# Is there a cooldown when training in a friendly gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

> You can train your Pokémon in a friendly battle, where **you select a single Pokémon to battle against another Pokémon in a friendly Gym**. The more you train, the more Prestige you can earn for your team’s Gym. ([Source](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222049647-Train-your-Pok%C3%A9mon-at-friendly-Gyms))

Provided you have the potions to heal your Pokemon, can you battle back-to-back and select the same trainer every time to battle, increasing Prestige and getting an XP bonus every time?

The wording of the official Niantic Labs source makes it seem as if you can select which trainer in a friendly gym you want to battle (and so I assume that is true). Is there a cooldown, or possibly do you have to battle the *next* trainer after defeating the first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can keep attacking a gym as often as you wish, provided you have the Pokémon with health to do it. I think there is a limit to how much prestige you can have and the level of the gym, but you can train at a gym as much as you want without a cooldown, and you will get experience from it every time.

source: personal experience

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no cooldown, but I think the bigger issue is that you are misunderstanding what it's saying. It's saying you select one of **your** Pokemon to battle against the gym. You do not get to choose who in the gym you battle. It's always in order from lowest CP to highest CP. So your question about having to battle a different trainer doesn't make sense; you always battle the same Pokemon in the same order unless the Pokemon in the gym have changed for some reason.

Comment: Yeah this was a while ago. I'm close to the gold training badge so I know you can't select who you want to train against, like you said it's always the gym order.

Answer (score -1):

Believe there is

After a few trainings it will just keep bouncing you to the gym screen

Probably implemented to save their servers

Comment: No. This is a common bug. I know what you're talking about but it's definitely not a cooldown. I trained ~150 times last night to boost prestige at a Gym Valor was trying to take.