# Why can't I train?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm at a friendly gym and I trained successfully twice in a row. On my third attempt the wonky GPS slightly moved my trainer outside the gym radius immediately ending the battle.

I moved myself closer so that this wouldn't happen, but now whenever I attempt to train it gets as far as the "GO" screen shown below:

[image]

Then it immediately exits back to the Gym. I have no idea why. As per my question **[here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/275166/125786)**, you should be able to train as many times as you want without cool down.

I've tried hard restarting, but I'm curious if this is a known bug or not because I've not seen anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty bad bug that is the fault of the server. There is no fix for it aside from just waiting it out for about 45 minutes and going to other gyms.

Source: Personal experience

Comment: How long about did you have to wait? Or did you not stick around that long. I'm leveling this Gym for a reason :-(

Comment: Sorry I did not stick around for that long. Perhaps you can try checking every 30 minutes to an hour?

Comment: Yeah I will then I'll let you update your answer with how long it took for me.

Comment: About 45 minutes..